# PHP Pagination, Page Number Keeps Appending to URL

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

I have a pagination system that requires the page number to be in the URL. The problem is that links to the next pages grab the 'current url' and this URL already contains the page number from a previous page, for example:

the pagination links grab the current URL `http://localhost/search/` and append their page number, result: `http://localhost/search/1`, `http://localhost/search/2` etc.
at the next page the following pagination links grab the current URL which might have a page number already in them! And so it appends again `http://localhost/search/1/2` and everything breaks.

I really don't want to use sessions for this. Using CodeIgniter `base_url()` does not return the controller and function that I need and if I use `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` then it also includes the domain. Any ideas how I might achieve this?

**EDIT**

Sample Code:

```
foreach ($reviews as $page){
        echo "<li><a href='".current_url()."/$page'>$page</a></li>";
}

echo '</ul>';
```

Comment: what does you anchor tag look like for the Next Page?

Comment: You might want to add the code that generates your links at the moment, it could help someone come up with an easy to implement solution.

Comment: @joseph4tw `<a href="http://localhost/search/top-rated/1</a>`

Comment: How about using a relative link? (eg. `echo "<li><a href='../$page'>$page</a></li>";` ? Might (probably will) cause problems if no page is specified, at the beginning - but you can work around that using an `if` or linking to `..../search/1` in the first place.

Comment: do you know the format of 'current_url'? i.e. does it always have a page number on it or can you identify easily the 'base part' of it that you need and then strip the excess off. you then append your page number info.

Comment: @ccKep Perfect it worked because there is no need to grab a URL. Also the page number is the last element added so I can have any number of parameters before it and still would work. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace your Link with a relative one:

```
echo "<li><a href='../$page'>$page</a></li>";
```

This assumes that the page is the last part of the URL and will need special handling if there's no page specified (and 1 is assumed).

Possible ways to handle that are

- using an `if` to see if a page was specified (if yes, use a relative link, if not simply append the next page number like you did until now).
- simply linking to the first page explicitly by appending `/1` when searching.

Comment: +1 Nice. I'll keep my answer there in case anyone wants to specify full URLs for their links.

Answer (score 0):

From the CI documentation here:

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html

Could you do something like this?

```
foreach ($reviews as $page){
        echo "<li><a href='".site_url("url/to/results")."/$page'>$page</a></li>";
}
```

Comment: He already has it working, see the comments for the original question. But I might aswell post it as an answer so the OP can accept it, sorry I haven't yet.